# Is there a way to reassign an argument within a function, and have it also affect the calling scope?

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

What I am trying to do is build a clone() function for Javascript objects. As you know the lack of native functionality for this in Javascript can be a pain. I have a great method to do it, but usability wise, it is awkward. Here is the function so far:

```
function clone(objectToClone) {
    var myClone = function() {};
    myClone.prototype = objectToClone;
    return [
        new myClone(),
        new myClone()
    ];
}
```

As you can see, currently I just return an array with both clones. This makes the usage look something like this:

```
// usage
var bar = new foo();
bar = clone(bar); // forks bar into two separate copies of bar (awkward)
// bar[0] is now clone 1
// bar[1] is now clone 2
```

What I would like to do, is be able to do something like the following:

```
function clone(objectToClone) {
    var myClone = function() {};
    myClone.prototype = objectToClone;
    objectToClone = new myClone(); // somehow magically?
    return new myClone();
}

// usage
var bar = new foo();
var baz = clone(bar); // returns a copy, and bar is now one of the copies as well.
// bar is now clone 1
// baz is now clone 2
```

Unfortunately this does not work, since assigning the argument does not affect the calling scope. I was hoping that someone might be able to help think up some js trickery that would allow me to use the function in the desired manor however. Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: why don't you want the copy to return the clone? What you could do is to pass the scope (like 'window') and the name of one ore more variables to your function that could be then replaced by clones.

Comment: @muffel having trouble picturing what you are saying. can you elaborate in an answer?

Comment: Not sure how to I feel about this implementation of `clone`; if for example you keep cloning an object, you will create an arbitrarily long prototype chain (for example, if you were cloning as part of a for-loop). Though if this is what you want, why don't you just do `return new myClone()`? *edit*: Ah, I see, then baz might be modified by side-effects on bar.

Comment: @ninjagecko i see what you are saying, but the only alternative I can think of is iterating the properties of the entire object, and assigning the same properties to a new object, which also has its drawbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your desired result, you would need to pass in an object with properties and then modify those properties.  That's the best way to get a reference in javascript that allows you to change the original.  You cannot change the original when it's just passed as an ordinary function argument.  Javascript doesn't have those types of references.

```
function clone(holder) {
    var myClone = function() {};
    myClone.prototype = holder.input;
    holder.input = new myClone(); // somehow magically?
    return new myClone();
}

// usage
var holder = {};
var holder.input = new foo();
var holder.output = clone(holder); // returns a copy, and holder.input is now a copy too
// holder.input is now clone 1
// holder.putput is now clone 2
```

Comment: unfortunately this is just about as awkward, but the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could have your clone function return the copy, while leaving the original alone.

If this is impossible or impractical for some reason, that is the best you can do:

```
var bar = new foo();
var clones = clone(bar);
bar = clones[0];
barCopy = clones[1];
```

Unless you resort to incredibly inelegant `eval` trickery.

I think what you really want is to just `return new myClone()` and never use `bar`. This actually makes things a bit more elegant (you can call it `bar_template` or something if desired), since you can now clone the original template.

Comment: no, because then modifying the original `bar` object affects the clone as well, basically equating to `var baz = bar;`, not an actual clone.

Comment: bar_template wouldn't be universally applicable. I would have to create a new function for each object I would want to clone.

Answer (score 0):

You wanted me to explain my comment, here you go:

```
function replaceClones(){
    for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++){
        var varName = arguments[i];
        this[varName] = getClone(this[varName]);
    }    
}

function getClone(obj){
    var Clone = function(){};
    Clone.prototype = obj;
    return new Clone();
}

replaceClones("varA","varB");
```

If you want another scope, just use

```
replaceClones.call(newScope,"varA","varB");
```